# Implement onItemClickListener in SegmentedBarView-Android

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to setup an on item click listener in SegmentedBarView-Android (https://github.com/gspd-mobi/SegmentedBarView-Android), but without success. Could you advise how this can be achieved ?

I'm using the following code to create a barView:

```
        SegmentedBarView barView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar_view);
        List<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();

        Segment segment1 = new Segment(min_sed,mix_sed,"", Color.parseColor("#12B6DE"));
        segment1.setCustomText(getString(R.string.segmentedbar_se_min));
        segments.add(segment1);

        Segment segment2 = new Segment(min_sed,max_sed,"", Color.parseColor("#82B6DE"));
        segment2.setCustomText(getString(R.string.segmentedbar_se_max));
        segments.add(segment2);

        barView.setSegments(segments);
```

After barView is created, I'd like to have a onClick listener which will identify on which segment(segment1, segment2) is clicked. Unfortunately barView extend View and have only setOnClickListener, which returns the id of the whole view, but not the segments when used.

Comment: post your code what you already have tried, can't help solve a problem if we dont know what you did in your code

Comment: posted in the question above